# multiple inline styles not displaying properly

Tags: html, inline

Sorry, a designer here (not a developer). I am having an issue with only the first attribute being applied and inability to apply any others after the first one. I know the best way is through CSS, but sometimes a need a quick simple job and can't spend the time to develop or edit a CSS properly.

Here's what I have, what is wrong?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center;" style="font-decoration-style:bold;" style="text-decoration-color:red;">Helloooo!</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: SALTY! Alon, I was unaware you needed to have a certain skill level (or ego) to use this website. If my basic questions, in a language that I am not 100% fluent, offend you, all I can say is to look away. Don't stare at the horror of such a simple question!... Oh, the humanity!

Answer (score 9):

Sorry but you can only have one attribute of a kind for each element in HTML.
Try this instead:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:red;">Helloooo!</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you rafaelcastrocourto! This helped. The only thing not working is the center attribute. Should this be handled differently (other than in CSS)?

Comment: It's working in the answer code, the css `text-align:center` does center the text (click "Run code snippet"). Can you explain better why you can't see it working?